# Is the sum behavior in pandas expected?

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point

**EDIT2**
I checked it in python2.7 and python3.6, with the same result.

Add a more copy-paste friendly version:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: from io import StringIO

In [3]: csv = u"""
   ...: Index,SH600000,SZ002222
   ...: 0,2145799.0,282838.0
   ...: 1,2104693.0,705100.0
   ...: 2,1228606.0,394897.0
   ...: 3,638308.0,276903.0
   ...: 4,387360.0,337920.0
   ...: 5,292297.0,198000.0
   ...: 6,402659.0,166301.0
   ...: 7,1287122.0,268300.0
   ...: 8,2039270.0,66000.0
   ...: 9,2232800.0,86107.0
   ...: 10,1809037.0,155093.0
   ...: 11,363093.0,79157.0
   ...: 12,708322.0,98592.0
   ...: 13,520142.0,96201.0
   ...: 14,671617.0,57053.0
   ...: 15,1049536.0,410847.0
   ...: 16,279062.0,132880.0
   ...: 17,982549.0,104566.0
   ...: 18,664100.0,104519.0
   ...: 19,989327.0,174801.0
   ...: 20,581799.0,110500.0
   ...: 21,521880.0,60200.0
   ...: 22,3483513.0,276500.0
   ...: 23,2841970.0,59907.0
   ...: 24,1107128.0,50800.0
   ...: 25,1176953.0,40150.0
   ...: 26,304900.0,46300.0
   ...: 27,412040.0,55309.0
   ...: 28,259642.0,9500.0
   ...: 29,425157.0,18700.0
   ...: 30,1379000.0,63900.0
   ...: 31,688590.0,92101.0
   ...: 32,456862.0,71399.0
   ...: 33,2490348.0,26600.0
   ...: 34,1004700.0,80800.0
   ...: 35,947848.0,28400.0
   ...: 36,1426061.0,37057.0
   ...: 37,1140738.0,68850.0
   ...: 38,551291.0,42870.0
   ...: 39,1434669.0,57550.0
   ...: 40,2356270.0,84300.0
   ...: 41,2000965.0,55823.0
   ...: 42,401515.0,47027.0
   ...: 43,732070.0,98550.0
   ...: 44,1670248.0,149350.0
   ...: 45,1508998.0,123200.0
   ...: 46,1466045.0,31200.0
   ...: 47,1665586.0,31700.0"""

In [4]: dat = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv.strip()), index_col='Index').astype('float32')

In [5]: dat.sum()
Out[5]: 
SH600000    55232496.0
SZ002222     6114618.0
dtype: float32

In [6]: dat.stack().sum(level=1)
Out[6]: 
SH600000    55232484.0
SZ002222     6114618.0
dtype: float32

In [7]: dat['SH600000'].sum()
Out[7]: 55232488.0

In [8]: pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.13.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64
machine: x86_64
processor: x86_64
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_US.UTF-8
LOCALE: None.None

pandas: 0.20.3
pytest: None
pip: 9.0.1
setuptools: 36.0.1
Cython: None
numpy: 1.13.1
scipy: 0.19.1
xarray: None
IPython: 5.4.0
sphinx: None
patsy: 0.4.1
dateutil: 2.6.0
pytz: 2017.2
blosc: None
bottleneck: None
tables: 3.4.2
numexpr: 2.6.2
feather: None
matplotlib: 2.0.2
openpyxl: None
xlrd: None
xlwt: None
xlsxwriter: None
lxml: None
bs4: None
html5lib: 0.999999999
sqlalchemy: None
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: 2.9.6
s3fs: None
pandas_gbq: None
pandas_datareader: None
```

---

I have a dataframe as following:

```
In [23]: dat
Out[23]: 
tid                   SH600000  SZ002222
datetime                                
2013-08-09 09:35:00  2145799.0  282838.0
2013-08-09 09:40:00  2104693.0  705100.0
2013-08-09 09:45:00  1228606.0  394897.0
2013-08-09 09:50:00   638308.0  276903.0
2013-08-09 09:55:00   387360.0  337920.0
2013-08-09 10:00:00   292297.0  198000.0
2013-08-09 10:05:00   402659.0  166301.0
2013-08-09 10:10:00  1287122.0  268300.0
2013-08-09 10:15:00  2039270.0   66000.0
2013-08-09 10:20:00  2232800.0   86107.0
2013-08-09 10:25:00  1809037.0  155093.0
2013-08-09 10:30:00   363093.0   79157.0
2013-08-09 10:35:00   708322.0   98592.0
2013-08-09 10:40:00   520142.0   96201.0
2013-08-09 10:45:00   671617.0   57053.0
2013-08-09 10:50:00  1049536.0  410847.0
2013-08-09 10:55:00   279062.0  132880.0
2013-08-09 11:00:00   982549.0  104566.0
2013-08-09 11:05:00   664100.0  104519.0
2013-08-09 11:10:00   989327.0  174801.0
2013-08-09 11:15:00   581799.0  110500.0
2013-08-09 11:20:00   521880.0   60200.0
2013-08-09 11:25:00  3483513.0  276500.0
2013-08-09 11:30:00  2841970.0   59907.0
2013-08-09 13:05:00  1107128.0   50800.0
2013-08-09 13:10:00  1176953.0   40150.0
2013-08-09 13:15:00   304900.0   46300.0
2013-08-09 13:20:00   412040.0   55309.0
2013-08-09 13:25:00   259642.0    9500.0
2013-08-09 13:30:00   425157.0   18700.0
2013-08-09 13:35:00  1379000.0   63900.0
2013-08-09 13:40:00   688590.0   92101.0
2013-08-09 13:45:00   456862.0   71399.0
2013-08-09 13:50:00  2490348.0   26600.0
2013-08-09 13:55:00  1004700.0   80800.0
2013-08-09 14:00:00   947848.0   28400.0
2013-08-09 14:05:00  1426061.0   37057.0
2013-08-09 14:10:00  1140738.0   68850.0
2013-08-09 14:15:00   551291.0   42870.0
2013-08-09 14:20:00  1434669.0   57550.0
2013-08-09 14:25:00  2356270.0   84300.0
2013-08-09 14:30:00  2000965.0   55823.0
2013-08-09 14:35:00   401515.0   47027.0
2013-08-09 14:40:00   732070.0   98550.0
2013-08-09 14:45:00  1670248.0  149350.0
2013-08-09 14:50:00  1508998.0  123200.0
2013-08-09 14:55:00  1466045.0   31200.0
2013-08-09 15:00:00  1665586.0   31700.0
```

I want to calculate the sum value of `SH600000` along `datetime`, and there are three ways:

```
In [24]: dat.sum()
Out[24]: 
tid
SH600000    55232496.0
SZ002222     6114618.0
dtype: float32

In [25]: dat.stack().sum(level='tid')
Out[25]: 
tid
SH600000    55232484.0
SZ002222     6114618.0
dtype: float32

In [26]: dat['SH600000'].sum()
Out[26]: 55232488.0
```

We can see that there are three different result for each way. I known the result is not accurate due to the precision limit of `float32`. But I expected that the three result should be the same **not-accurate** one.

**EDIT**
@Ken The record format of `dat` as following:

```
In [7]: dat.to_records()
Out[7]: 
rec.array([(datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 9, 35),  2145799.,  282838.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 9, 40),  2104693.,  705100.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 9, 45),  1228606.,  394897.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 9, 50),   638308.,  276903.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 9, 55),   387360.,  337920.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 0),   292297.,  198000.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 5),   402659.,  166301.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 10),  1287122.,  268300.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 15),  2039270.,   66000.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 20),  2232800.,   86107.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 25),  1809037.,  155093.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 30),   363093.,   79157.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 35),   708322.,   98592.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 40),   520142.,   96201.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 45),   671617.,   57053.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 50),  1049536.,  410847.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 55),   279062.,  132880.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 11, 0),   982549.,  104566.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 11, 5),   664100.,  104519.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 11, 10),   989327.,  174801.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 11, 15),   581799.,  110500.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 11, 20),   521880.,   60200.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 11, 25),  3483513.,  276500.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 11, 30),  2841970.,   59907.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 5),  1107128.,   50800.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 10),  1176953.,   40150.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 15),   304900.,   46300.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 20),   412040.,   55309.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 25),   259642.,    9500.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 30),   425157.,   18700.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 35),  1379000.,   63900.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 40),   688590.,   92101.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 45),   456862.,   71399.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 50),  2490348.,   26600.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 55),  1004700.,   80800.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 0),   947848.,   28400.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 5),  1426061.,   37057.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 10),  1140738.,   68850.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 15),   551291.,   42870.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 20),  1434669.,   57550.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 25),  2356270.,   84300.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 30),  2000965.,   55823.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 35),   401515.,   47027.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 40),   732070.,   98550.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 45),  1670248.,  149350.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 50),  1508998.,  123200.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 55),  1466045.,   31200.),
           (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 15, 0),  1665586.,   31700.)], 
          dtype=[(u'datetime', 'O'), (u'SH600000', '<f4'), (u'SZ002222', '<f4')])
```

@S Ringne I `reset_index` as you mentioned, but without luck:

```
In [53]: dat.reset_index(inplace=True)

In [54]: dat.head()
Out[54]: 
tid            datetime   SH600000  SZ002222
0   2013-08-09 09:35:00  2145799.0  282838.0
1   2013-08-09 09:40:00  2104693.0  705100.0
2   2013-08-09 09:45:00  1228606.0  394897.0
3   2013-08-09 09:50:00   638308.0  276903.0
4   2013-08-09 09:55:00   387360.0  337920.0

In [55]: dat[['SH600000', 'SZ002222']].sum()
Out[55]: 
tid
SH600000    55232496.0
SZ002222     6114618.0
dtype: float32

In [56]: dat[['SH600000', 'SZ002222']].stack().sum(level=1)
Out[56]: 
tid
SH600000    55232484.0
SZ002222     6114618.0
dtype: float32

In [57]: dat['SH600000'].sum()
Out[57]: 55232488.0
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting your kernel? It would be helpful if you can give the data in a format which we could copy-paste and run on our own machines, e.g. the output of `dat.to_json()` or `dat.to_records()`. Also, floating point arithmetic is much more accurate than this to be causing any noticeable rounding error.

Comment: How would restarting the kernel help?

Comment: @Eastsun, this seems some anomaly, can you first reset_index of dat. and then try it once? dat,reset_index(inplace=True)

Comment: @KenWei I support the record format after edited.

Comment: @SRingne the `reset_index` doesn't change anything.

Comment: It looks like you have 32 bit floats, could that be the problem?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/46970123/270986

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have some variables over-written as the same dataset gives me right result.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

val1 = [(datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 9, 35),  2145799.,  282838.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 9, 40),  2104693.,  705100.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 9, 45),  1228606.,  394897.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 9, 50),   638308.,  276903.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 9, 55),   387360.,  337920.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 0),   292297.,  198000.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 5),   402659.,  166301.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 10),  1287122.,  268300.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 15),  2039270.,   66000.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 20),  2232800.,   86107.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 25),  1809037.,  155093.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 30),   363093.,   79157.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 35),   708322.,   98592.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 40),   520142.,   96201.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 45),   671617.,   57053.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 50),  1049536.,  410847.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 10, 55),   279062.,  132880.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 11, 0),   982549.,  104566.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 11, 5),   664100.,  104519.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 11, 10),   989327.,  174801.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 11, 15),   581799.,  110500.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 11, 20),   521880.,   60200.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 11, 25),  3483513.,  276500.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 11, 30),  2841970.,   59907.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 5),  1107128.,   50800.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 10),  1176953.,   40150.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 15),   304900.,   46300.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 20),   412040.,   55309.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 25),   259642.,    9500.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 30),   425157.,   18700.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 35),  1379000.,   63900.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 40),   688590.,   92101.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 45),   456862.,   71399.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 50),  2490348.,   26600.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 13, 55),  1004700.,   80800.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 0),   947848.,   28400.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 5),  1426061.,   37057.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 10),  1140738.,   68850.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 15),   551291.,   42870.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 20),  1434669.,   57550.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 25),  2356270.,   84300.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 30),  2000965.,   55823.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 35),   401515.,   47027.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 40),   732070.,   98550.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 45),  1670248.,  149350.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 50),  1508998.,  123200.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 14, 55),  1466045.,   31200.),
       (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 15, 0),  1665586.,   31700.)]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(val1,columns =['datetime','SH600000','SZ002222'])
df2['SZ002222'] = df2['SZ002222'].astype(np.float64)
df2['SH600000'] = df2['SH600000'].astype(np.float64)


 df2.sum()
Out[237]: 
SH600000    55232485.0
SZ002222     6114618.0

df2['SH600000'].sum()
Out[239]: 55232485.0
```

Check this link for numpy array dtype different behaviour:

[Numpy casting float32 to float64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45949263/6803114)

Comment: Your dtype is float64, And mine is float32.

Comment: you can change the dtype from float32 to float64. See edit

Comment: I known how to change dtype. My question is why the results are different when dtype is float32.

Comment: @Eastsun Sir please check the link i shared below