# Why does Python numpy float32 / int division gives a float64 result?

Tags: python, numpy, data-structures, floating-point

I have a numpy.float32 matrix V, then I did a division with a integer scalar value:

```
V = V/num
```

where num is an integer. The outcome is somewhat surprising that V is converted to a numpy.float64 matrix.

Can anyone help understand why this is so?

Thanks!

Comment: What, *exactly* is `num`?

Comment: It's probably because casting int to float32 is considered unsafe by numpy (try 'np.can_cast(int, np.float32`)

Comment: If I use an `int`, I still get an array of `np.float32`. Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @PaulPanzer it depends on the `int` in question, e.g. `np.can_cast(2**15, np.float32)` returns `True` for me, but `np.can_cast(2**16, np.float32)` returns `False`

Comment: @Paul Panzer np.can_cast(int, np.float32) does give a False. My understanding is that python uses int32 be default, then why converting int32 to numpy.float32 is a problematic operation? numpy.float32 has a range large enough to handle a conversion from int32.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949263/numpy-casting-float32-to-float64

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, YC0, user2357112 Good points thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `Vtest = np.zeros([1,1]).astype('float32')`
`Vest_new = Vtest/65536`
`type(Vest_new[0,0]))`

Comment: If `num` is smaller or equal to 65535 (int16), the float32 won't be changed. The problem seems come from an int32.

Comment: Just a heads up that the linked Q/A has this very informative [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html)

Comment: Worth noting that numpy uses `int` to refer to the C `long`, which is sometimes `int32` and sometimes `int64`, depending on your platform - this is why @juanpa.arrivillaga cannot reproduce this, most likely

Comment: @YC0 "python" doesn't have sized-integers. Python `int` objects are arbitrarily large. Which is why python is happy to evaluate `2**128`

Comment: @  user2357112,  Eric, juanpa.arrivillaga,  Paul Panzer, thanks a lot! I think I have a much better idea now. It's sort of reasonable since numpy determines that float32 can not hold all the values of int32 losslessly. So that's why when I increased 65535 to 65536 will change the resullting type as a float64.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Numpy.result_type](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html), numpy.float32 can not hold int32 losslessly. When the operation is with an int32, numpy will promotes the resulting value as a float64. Also according to @Eric, the actual int type may change in different environment, so a pre-test is a good practice to avoid some potential surprise.

A previous similar question is suggested for further reading:[Numpy casting float32 to float64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949263/numpy-casting-float32-to-float64)
. Numpy has a different treatment for purely scalar operations and the operations involving an array. In this case, the division operation involves a ndarray, so when `num` is smaller than 65536 but larger thant 255, numpy converts it as int16. Numpy determines int16 can be cast to float32 losslessly while int32 can't. This is shown by `np.can_cast(np.int16, np.float32)` gives `True` but `np.can_cast(np.int32, np.float32)` gives `False`.

Thanks for the insightful comments under the question. This answer is a short summary of these comments.