# How can I force a numpy scalar*array multiplication to have a float64 result?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I define a constant of dtype `float64` and an array of ones of dtype `float32`:

```
c = np.arccos(-1)
ones = np.array([1,1,1], dtype='float32')
print(c.dtype, ones.dtype)
```

`float64 float32`

If I multiply the scalar by the entire array, I get a result with dtype `float32`:

```
result_array = c*ones
print(result_array, result_array.dtype)
```

`[3.1415927 3.1415927 3.1415927] float32`

However if I multiply the scalar by just the first element, I get a result of dtype `float64`:

```
result_scalar = c*ones[0]
print(result_scalar, result_scalar.dtype)
```

`3.141592653589793 float64`

How can I perform the multiplication `c*ones` in double precision, such that the resulting array is of dtype `float64`? (Without multiplying each element by the constant individually, of course.)

(I've reviewed this related question/answer, which has some good information on the dtype resulting from Numpy scalar and array operations, but doesn't quite answer my question: [Numpy casting float32 to float64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949263/numpy-casting-float32-to-float64))

Comment: `c = np.arccos([-1])` appears to do the trick.  `ones = np.ones(3)` should also make a 64 array.

Comment: `result_array = c*ones.astype(np.float64)` will result in a float64 array, or just create the "ones" as a float64 array.